# Are the moves/rules of standard chess delicately balanced?

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory, chess

<sub>(While the world chess championship is in progress in Sochi...)</sub>

Is there mathematical evidence that standard chess is somehow
optimally (or unusally) rich compared to
other possible chess-like games, e.g., using
[fairy chess pieces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fairy_chess_piece) 
and/or following [chess variant rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_variant)?

I am wondering if chess is something like 
[Conway's game of Life](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway's_Game_of_Life)
in that its moves/rules are delicately balanced to achieve
[Turing completeness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness);
one can build [a Universal Turing Machine (UTM) in Life](http://rendell-attic.org/gol/tm.htm).

Here, I suppose, we must talk about "infinite chess,"
in the sense employed in

> Dan Brumleve, Joel David Hamkins, Philipp Schlicht.
>   "The mate-in-$n$ problem of infinite chess is decidable." 2012.
>   ([arXiv link](http://arxiv.org/abs/1201.5597)).

An alternative to the "delicately balanced" hypothesis is that the moves & rules
are a historical accident, and many nearby variants of standard
chess have (or may have) similar mathematical properties.
To ask specific questions:

> **Q1**. Can infinite chess simulate a UTM?
>
> **Q2**. Are nearby chess variants analogously powerful,
>   or does standard chess (seem to) have just the right complexity properties?

---

**Update**. Both questions are largely answered in the comments.
**Q1** is open in a formal sense
but the likely answer is *Yes*, $\infty$-chess can simulate a UTM.
For **Q2**, there is every reason to believe that chess rules are *not* delicately
balanced, that likely most reasonable variants would have the same complexity properties.

Comment: I have thought about this a great deal, and so far haven't made progress. It seems to be more tractable if you allow the set-up position to involve infinitely many pieces, although they should follow some extremely regular pattern, if not be periodic or eventually periodic. That is, in order to simulate the Turing machine, it will help to have a lot of structure already on the chessboard, to provide the structure of the cells. One idea I looked at is that the black king, say, should play the role of the head, moving from one room to the next, with other pieces playing the roles of the states.

Comment: All the moves should be forced, in accordance with the TM program transitions. So the king is forced to enter a room, and finds it in a certain configuration (the cell contents), and is forced by the state-pieces to move either to the next or the previous room, while the configuration of the room is set to the correct new value and the new state is set up for the next step.

Comment: Chess is EXPTIME-complete: seeA. S. Fraenkel and D. Lichtenstein, Computing a perfect strategy for n*n chess requires time exponential in n, Proc. 8th Int. Coll. Automata, Languages, and Programming, Springer LNCS 115 (1981) 278-293 and J. Comb. Th. A 31 (1981) 199-214. In some sense this implies that you can simulate a Turing machine on it. But in that sense it is not unusual; I would expect the same to be true of most fairy chess variants.

Comment: Making an analogy with the categorization of one-dimensional cellular automata in Wolframs NKS, it would not be surprising if a positive fraction of all "random" chess variants with fairy pieces have the properties you ask for.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with the "delicately balanced" metaphor, because the various computational models that are Turing complete, such as Turing machines, register machines and so on, tend to be robust rather than delicate, and retain their Turing completeness after diverse modifications (restricted instruction sets, big alphabets, many tapes, few tapes, and so on). The fact that these models all turned out equivalent was important evidence in favor of the Church-Turing thesis, that we've got the right model of computation. Conway's game is an outlier in this respect, I suppose.

Comment: Can someone give an example of a "non-rich" chess? I.e., can we change the number/position/allowed moves of the pieces so that the game becomes boring? Of course, exclude trivial solutions, like if the king can be taken in the first move.

Comment: Another point to make is that we would not discuss chess if it was not interesting. People invent new games all the time, but only the interesting ones "survives".

Comment: It would be remarkable if the rules of chess were *very* delicately balanced, because there are lots of ad hoc rules of chess that have been introduced to address perceived practical deficiencies. The rules for pawns are really weird (initial move of two spaces, capturing, en passant, promotion); ditto for castling. The rule that the game ends with checkmate rather than the capture of the king is also weird if you think about it. And of course the fifty-move rule is the ultimate example of mathematical anathema.